# retrieving firebase data to listview with a unique ID using android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve my data from firebase to android studio listview? I watch many tutorials on youtube. I use the codes of what did the tutorial gave, but it doesn't work on mine and also every data in my firebase has a unique ID to separate each data.

Here are the codes that I used:

```
public class ExisActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mdatabase;
private ListView mListView;

private ArrayList<String> marralist = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exis);
    mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvexist);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,marralist);
    mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

 }
}
```

and this is the other code that i used to get the data:

```
public class SaveData {
public String getEtOwnername() {
    return etOwnername;
}

public void setEtOwnername(String etOwnername) {
    this.etOwnername = etOwnername;
}

public String getEtAnimalname() {
    return etAnimalname;
}

public void setEtAnimalname(String etAnimalname) {
    this.etAnimalname = etAnimalname;
}

public String getEtAddress() {
    return etAddress;
}

public void setEtAddress(String etAddress) {
    this.etAddress = etAddress;
}

public String getEtContactNo() {
    return etContactNo;
}

public void setEtContactNo(String etContactNo) {
    this.etContactNo = etContactNo;
}

public String getEtDobAge() {
    return etDobAge;
}

public void setEtDobAge(String etDobAge) {
    this.etDobAge = etDobAge;
}

public String getEtEmail() {
    return etEmail;
}

public void setEtEmail(String etEmail) {
    this.etEmail = etEmail;
}

public String getEtClinicalNotes() {
    return etClinicalNotes;
}

public void setEtClinicalNotes(String etClinicalNotes) {
    this.etClinicalNotes = etClinicalNotes;
}

public String getEtMedication() {
    return etMedication;
}

public void setEtMedication(String etMedication) {
    this.etMedication = etMedication;
}

public String getEtPayMent() {
    return etPayMent;
}

public void setEtPayMent(String etPayMent) {
    this.etPayMent = etPayMent;
}

public SaveData(String etOwnername, String etAnimalname, String etAddress, String etContactNo, String etDobAge, String etEmail, String etClinicalNotes, String etMedication, String etPayMent) {

    this.etOwnername = etOwnername;
    this.etAnimalname = etAnimalname;
    this.etAddress = etAddress;
    this.etContactNo = etContactNo;
    this.etDobAge = etDobAge;
    this.etEmail = etEmail;
    this.etClinicalNotes = etClinicalNotes;
    this.etMedication = etMedication;
    this.etPayMent = etPayMent;
}
```

this is my DB structure of my fire base i'm also new to fire base

{
    "rules":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
}

}

Can any help me? please provide some link

PLEASE RESPECT MY POST

Comment: post your firebase DB structure with question

Comment: Sorry cant post my DB structures.... the document of the system on the other hands ... my classmate has in it.. and if i made my own db structures it will take long...

but i will do it

Comment: Don't let it go. You are damn close to the solution.  [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) might be of some help.